# What happens to socket when the internet connection goes off suddenly?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server and many clients. My clients send messages through server. If a client connects to server, my server puts socket reference of this client to a Sock array. If another client sends message to this first client server checks whether first client is connected to server or not using a boolean array, if it is online then sends message to first client using the socket reference in array otherwise sends messages to database.
Every client sends close signal before logout to server so that it can update the boolean array.But if internet connection of first client goes off suddenly ,then boolean variable in the array will still be true. For this purpose i want to make a thread in server which checks boolean array,if any index in array is true ,i want to check whether socket corresponding to it is open or not. What method of socket should i use- socket.isConnected() or socket.isClosed() or any other?

Comment: 'if internet connection of first client goes off suddenly' - what does that mean?  The problem is that 'the internet' does not really exist as an entity you can connect to, so you cannot detect connection to it, or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to be sure a connection is working is by receiving a heartbeat, or message at a regular interval.
There is `isConnectd()` which means; have I ever connected and `isClosed()` which means; did I call `close()` on my side, but these don't do what you might want.

Comment: If internet connection goes off how can i use socket reference to check whether it is still connected? What will happen to this socket?

Comment: @abc like I said, the only way is to expect a message/data to be sent to you and if it doesn't get sent, you time-out the socket connection.

Comment: Now i am making a thread from my service which sends some message to server at regular interval . But when service is stopped this thread is not stopping by itself . How to handle this so if my service is stopped, on server socket timeout can happen.

Comment: You need a thread which regularly checks that you have read some data from a connection e.g. set a timestamp of the last read somewhere. Where this exceed some timeout, close the Socket which will trigger an exception on a blocking thread. You can use one heartbeat monitor thread for all your connections.

Comment: Thanks all issues handled. I was sending a message to server on logging off so on that time  server closes the socket and an exception is created in thread so thread terminate and if internet connection goes off, a timeout exception occurs and in catch block server sets boolean value corresponding to that socket to false in the array.